# Solving two simple optimization problems simultaneously

Tags: optimization

I have two optimization problems to solve simultaneously.

The problems are

$$\max_{x}xF(a-x+y)$$ and $$\max_y yF(b-y+x)$$.

Here, $a$ and $b$ are scalars and $F$ is a cdf. Is there any technique or easy way that I can use to solve for a solution $(x,y)$?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "solve simultaneously". Are you hoping for an $(x,y)$ pair that will *simultaneously* maximize both objective functions? Are you hoping for some tradeoff between them? Is [multi-objective optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization) the sort of approach you are looking for?

Comment: Also I'll just note, although it's probably clear already, that your functions are nonconvex, so that may add to your headaches, depending on what you are trying to do.